# Jquery WYSIWYG with image uploader

Tags: jquery, image, wysiwyg, uploader

I'm driving nuts around here. I'm building a CodeIgniter CMS and I need to use rich text areas. Image uploading is a must. I've been trying NicEdit all weekend, and it has great and simple image uploading but it shows some really strange issues on IE8 that I can't fix. So...I'm ready to try something else. I've seen FCKeditor, CKeditor, Xinha, etc. I really don't care hoy it plays with CodeIgniter, since my image uploading is gonna be an independent PHP function, with no conection with CodeIgniter. But it's a must that it plays nice on the major browsers. Any suggestions?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally resolved this issue using TinyMCE and a wonderful plugin called [TinyMCE Image Upload](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinymceimageupl/)

It was a little bit rough to get it working but I made it.

Comment: Although, I can't make it work properly on IE. Any suggestions?